# How to link to file using asset_id

Tags: assets

I want to create a template that will show a full size image and all the metadata.
So the url would be something like siteurl/photo/221 with the 221 being the asset_id.

I thought I would use the tag {asset_id} within my tag pair to build the url link but it just returns {asset_id} rather than the number.

I then thought I'd use something like:

```
{exp:assets:files asset_id="{segment_2"}
    <img src="{url}" title="{title}" alt="{description}" />
{/exp:assets:files}
```

in the photo template, but it doesn't work.

So is it a bug that {asset_id} doesn't work, and is my code example the right way to get the data for a single image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in Assets 2.1.1

Answer (score 1):

{asset_id} as a variable isn't currently parsing, which is a known bug - but you're trying it as a parameter.  I don't actually see it listed in our [docs](http://pixelandtonic.com/assets/docs/templates#assets%3afiles).  I'd be happy to add it to our list for consideration as a future addition though.

Right now, it looks like to get your single file data you'd need to use the Property and Metadata search from the above-linked page (toward the bottom).

Comment: Is there a way to access the Assets data without going through a channel:entries tag?